# Codeigniter showing error: No database selected

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, dbforge

I am using Codeigniter's DBForge class to create a database and table within that database.

Here is code:

```
if ($this->dbforge->create_database('new_db')) {
     $fields = array(
         'blog_id' => array(
              'type' => 'INT',
              'constraint' => 5,
              'unsigned' => TRUE,
              'auto_increment' => TRUE
          ),
          'blog_title' => array(
              'type' => 'VARCHAR',
              'constraint' => '100',
          ),
          'blog_author' => array(
              'type' => 'VARCHAR',
              'constraint' => '100',
              'default' => 'King of Town',
          ),
          'blog_description' => array(
              'type' => 'TEXT',
              'null' => TRUE,
          ),
     );
     $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
     $this->dbforge->add_key('blog_id', TRUE);
     $this->dbforge->create_table('blog', TRUE);
}
```

The above mentioned code is written inside index function of controller. When the following code is executed, it shows error as, **No database selected**. Does anyone have ant idea why it is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify

```
 $db['default']['database'] = "new_db";
```

in database.php

Answer (score 1):

Just refer to database.php file inside application/config folder. Make sure you have proper values for database name and other things in the following lines present in database.php file

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'your username', //By default it is root
'password' => 'your password', //By default this field is empty
'database' => 'database name',//The error that you are getting is because of this only. Specify your database name here
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the default database in config/database.php and it is still not working, you probably should save the file in case you forget to do that.