# creating table in mysql database with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I try to create a table with codeigniter in mysql DB with following code:

```
$posts_fields=array(
        'id'=>array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => 5,'unsigned' => TRUE),
        'title'=>array('type' =>'VARCHAR','constraint' => 100),
        'content'=>array('type'=>'text'),
        'create_time'=>array('type'=>'INT','constraint'=>12));

    $this->dbforge->add_field($posts_fields);
    $this->dbforge->create_table('posts');
```

but anytime get error "NO DATABASE SELECTED".

how can I select a database to create tables in it??
(this database is not default database)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392828/codeigniter-showing-error-no-database-selected

Comment: I try to create table in a database that is not default database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at [Codeigniter showing error: No database selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392828/codeigniter-showing-error-no-database-selected)

If you are using different database then use following,

`$this->db->query('use db2');`

and then put your code.

Comment: glad, i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

[database.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebtQa.png) Declare database name in the database.php

This may solve your error!

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image. Look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2915423) why it's not a good idea to use images or screenshots.